# "LinkedIn API - 'This application is not allowed to create application tokens' issue"

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

My main problem is getting the token. I can’t go further than this step.I am encountering an issue while trying to obtain an OAuth2 token from the LinkedIn API

I am encountering an issue while trying to obtain an OAuth2 token from the LinkedIn API using the following endpoint: [https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={client_secret}](https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=%7BclientId%7D&client_secret=%7Bclient_secret%7D). The response I receive is:

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

I have verified that the client_id and client_secret are correct, and I have the necessary permissions for the application. However, I am still unable to generate the access token.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have insights into resolving this problem? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!